# Read file error in Python, even though print function is printing the list

Tags: python

I have been trying different ways of writing this code but cannot get past this.  Currently the program will run all the way to the `write_names(list)` function and create the file, and the print function will print the sorted list.  The program refuses to get the user input for the `search_names()` function but it will print anything I ask it to.

Debug highlights: `while index < len(list)` and in the debug I\O only states "read file error".  Hopefully someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
'#  Abstract:     This program creates a list of names.  The list is printed,
'#                sorted, printed again, written to file, and searched.
'#=============================================================================

'#define the main function

def main():

    #try:
        ##open data file for read
        #infile = open('names.txt', 'r')

    #call get_names function
    list = get_names()

    #call print function
    print_names(list)

    #sort list
    list.sort()

    #print sorted list
    print_names(list)

    #write sorted list to new file
    write_names(list)

    #allow user to search list
    search_names(list)



def get_names():

    try:
        infile = open('names.txt', 'r')
        #read file contents into a list
        list = infile.readlines()
        #close file
        infile.close()
        #strip \n from each element
        index = 0
        while index < len(list):
            list[index] = list[index].rstrip('\n')
            index += 1
        return list
    except IOError:
        print 'Read file error'

def print_names(list):

    #print header
    print '******************'
    #print list line by line
    index = 0
    while index < len(list):
        print list[index]
        index += 1
    return

def write_names(list):

    #open file for writing
    outfile = open('sortedNames.txt', 'w')
    #write the list to the file
    for item in list:
        outfile.write(str(item) + '\n')
    #close file
    outfile.close()

def search_names(list):

    #set user test variable
    again = 'Y'
    while again.upper == 'Y':
        #get search from user   
        search = raw_input('Enter a name to search for: ')
        #open list for search
        if search in list:
            try:
                item_index = list.index(search)
                print search, 'found.', item_index
            except ValueError:
                print search, 'not found.'



main()
'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend not using "list" since it's a built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `upper` is a function, and you are not calling it.  Your `while` in `search_names()` should read:

```
while again.upper() == 'Y':
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
#strip \n from each element
index = 0
while index < len(list):
    list[index] = list[index].rstrip('\n')
    index += 1
return list
```

just use this list comprehension:

```
lines = infile.readlines()
infile.close()

return [ line.strip() for line in lines ]
```

edit:

It looks like you are using an index and a `while` loop where a `for` loop can be used.

Instead of:

```
while index < len(list):
    print list[index]
    index += 1
```

use:

```
    # using name_list instead of list
    for name in name_list:
        print name
```

also, your search_names() function looks flawed:

```
def search_names(list):

    #set user test variable
    again = 'Y'
    while again.upper == 'Y':
        #get search from user   
        search = raw_input('Enter a name to search for: ')
        #open list for search
        if search in list:
            try:
                item_index = list.index(search)
                print search, 'found.', item_index
            except ValueError:
                print search, 'not found.'
```

would never exit (again is never reassigned). try:

```
def search_names(names_list):
    again = 'Y'
    while again.upper() == 'Y':
        s_name = raw_input('Enter a name to search for: ')
        if s_name in names_list:
            print s_name, 'found.', names_list.index(s_name)
        else:
            print search, 'not found.'
        again = raw_input('Search for another name (Y|N)?: ')
```

or:

```
def search_names(names_list):
    again = 'Y'
    while again == 'Y':
        s_name = raw_input('Enter a name to search for: ')
        try:
            idx = names_list.index(s_name)
            print s_name, 'found.', idx
        except ValueError:
            print search, 'not found.'
        again = raw_input('Search for another name (Y|N)?: ').upper()
```

Which brings up the issue of when to catch exceptions vs using an if statement:

from [**`msdn`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The method you choose depends on how
>   often you expect the event to occur.
>   If the event is truly exceptional and
>   is an error (such as an unexpected
>   end-of-file), using exception handling
>   is better because less code is
>   executed in the normal case. If the
>   event happens routinely, using the
>   programmatic method to check for
>   errors is better. In this case, if an
>   exception occurs, the exception will
>   take longer to handle.

Answer (score 0):

1. Comments begin with `#`, not `'#` - you are making every other line of your header a docstring.
2. You are using an index to iterate across lists, which is inefficient - just iterate on the list items.
3. Calling a variable `list` is bad because it prevents you from accessing the list() datatype.
4. Using `with` is a more reliable replacement for open() .. close()
5. `again.upper` is a function reference - you have to **call** the function, ie `again.upper()`.
6. You never change the value of `again` - this will be an infinite loop!
7. You test `if search in list` but then do a try..except block which will only fail if it is *not* in the list (ie you are testing for the same failure twice).

.

```
#
# Operate on a list of names
#

def load_names(fname):
    try:
        with open(fname, 'r') as inf:
            return [line.strip() for line in inf]
    except IOError:
        print "Error reading file '{0}'".format(fname)
        return []

def print_names(namelist):
    print '******************'
    print '\n'.join(namelist)

def write_names(namelist, fname):
    with open(fname, 'w') as outf:
        outf.write('\n'.join(namelist))

def search_names(namelist):
    while True:
        lookfor = raw_input('Enter a name to search for (or nothing to quit): ').strip()
        if lookfor:
            try:
                ind = namelist.index(lookfor)
                print("{0} found.".format(lookfor))
            except ValueError:
                print("{0} not found.".format(lookfor))
        else:
            break

def main():
    namelist = load_names('names.txt')
    print_names(namelist)
    namelist.sort()
    print_names(namelist)
    write_names(namelist, 'sorted_names.txt')
    search_names(namelist)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```